# How to prove $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{6(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, algorithms, sorting

I am working on a problem of median of 3 quicksort. Any element $2 \leq i \leq n-1$ in the array has a probability of $p_i=\frac{6(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$ being chosen as a pivot. So, if we sum up all the probabilities, they should equal to 1. Now, how to prove $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{6(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{6(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac{6}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(i-1)(n-i)$$ Now $$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(i-1)(n-i)=(n+1)\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}i-n \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}1- \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}i^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Put i = r+1,
Summation will change from 1 to n-2 and numerator will change to r(n-r-1), now use summation of 1st n natural numbers, sum of square of 1st n natural numbers, simplify it u will have your result.

Comment: Or I can use summation from 1 to n, then subtract 1 and n from the result.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac {6(i-1)(n-i)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}
&=\frac 6{n(n-1)(n-2)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i(n-i-1)\\
&=\frac {3!}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i}^{n-2}i\\
&=\frac 1{\binom n3}\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^j i
&&(1\le i\le j\le n-2)\\
&=\frac 1{\binom n3}\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\binom {j+1}2\\
&=\frac 1{\binom n3}\binom n3\\
&=1\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1. In your first sum, the numerator should be $6\left(i - 1\right)\left(n - \color{#f00}{i}\right)$. Otherwise, it's a fine answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin - Thanks for the upvote and comments! Fixed.